# Creating methods with a macro based on the names of an enum

Tags: macros, crystal-lang

Having a struct with the following enum:

```
struct Payment
  enum Status
    Open
    Paid
    Failed

    def to_s
      super.downcase
    end
  end

  getter status : String
end
```

How can I access the enum names in a macro to create methods like `open?`, `paid?` and `failed?`?

**SOLUTION**

Based on @Jonne Haß' proposal, this is what I wanted to achieve:

```
{% for value in Status.constants %}
  {% downcased = value.stringify.downcase %}
  def {{ downcased.id }}?
    {{ downcased }} == status
  end
{% end %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [TypeNode#constants](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.33.0/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html#constants:Crystal::Macros::ArrayLiteral(MacroId)-instance-method):

```
struct Payment
  enum Status
    Open
    Paid
    Failed
  end

  getter status : Status = Status::Open

  {% begin %}
    delegate({{Status.constants.map {|value| value.stringify.downcase + "?" }.join(", ").id}}, to: status)
  {% end %}
end
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Although, in my case the value of `status` is a lower case `String` coming from an API. But `NodeType#constants` is exactly what I needed.